# Unslider dots function not showing

Tags: function, slider

I'm building a website where there is a slider on top, I wanted to use the unslider because it seems very easy.

According to the site you should just use the function- `dots: true`

I have that, but my slider doesn't have any slides.

[The site where I'm trying to set things up](http://balder.ucn.dk/1011815/2.semester/ferslevmureren-test).

(its a school project)

Comment: Doh! didn't see that
This should work

http://balder.ucn.dk/1011815/2.semester/ferslevmureren/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding some CSS.

```
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .4;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.dots li.active {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Does unisider provide this css or did you write this urself , or did u get it from http://unslider.com/style.css , its importent to know , because there are alot of issues with this plugin . when i mean issues , i mean confusion . did u write that CSS  by urself ??

Answer (score 1):

Just go to unslider.css file and add:

```
.unslider {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*Added*/
    position: relative;
}
```

And in unslider-dots.css add:

```
/*added*/
.unslider-nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 2%;
}
```

You just gotta say on your script `nav:true` and `dots:true`.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: I think this is more relevant at this date.